# How to drop rows in a df based on NaN values in specific columns not using column names but integer position for the subset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, position, nan, drop

I have a dataframe with 9 columns (long cryptic column names) and ~1000 rows. I want to drop/delete merely the rows where the values in column 2 and 3 are NaN.

I know there is `DataFrame.dropna(subset=[])` but I don't want to select the columns by label but by position.

Is there a way to do it? Renaming the columns is no option.

SOLUTION for me:
`df.dropna(subset=df.columns[[2,3]], how='all')`

---

EDIT:
This are some rows of my dataframe: (the important columns are Temp. and Event)

```
              Datum Zeit   Zeitzone  \
Anz.                                  
926  2019-09-17 09:00:00  GMT+02:00   
927  2019-09-17 10:00:00  GMT+02:00   
928  2019-09-17 11:00:00  GMT+02:00   
929  2019-09-17 12:00:00  GMT+02:00   
930  2019-09-17 13:00:00  GMT+02:00   
931  2019-09-17 13:10:32  GMT+02:00   
932  2019-09-17 13:11:21  GMT+02:00   
933  2019-09-17 13:11:41  GMT+02:00   
934  2019-09-17 13:11:42  GMT+02:00   
935  2019-09-17 13:11:53  GMT+02:00   

      Temp., °C (LGR S/N: 20009596, SEN S/N: 20009596, LBL: 1m)  \
Anz.                                                              
926                                              12.401           
927                                              13.942           
928                                              15.760           
929                                              15.569           
930                                              15.187           
931                                                 NaN           
932                                                 NaN           
933                                                 NaN           
934                                                 NaN           
935                                                 NaN           

      Event, units (LGR S/N: 20009596, SEN S/N: 20009596, LBL: 0,2 mm Niederschlag)  \
Anz.                                                                                  
926                                                 NaN                               
927                                                 NaN                               
928                                                 NaN                               
929                                                 NaN                               
930                                                 NaN                               
931                                               163.0                               
932                                                 NaN                               
933                                                 NaN                               
934                                                 NaN                               
935                                               163.0                               

     Notiz Koppler verbunden (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                               
926                                          NaN   
927                                          NaN   
928                                          NaN   
929                                          NaN   
930                                          NaN   
931                                          NaN   
932                                Protokolliert   
933                                          NaN   
934                                Protokolliert   
935                                          NaN   

     Koppler abgetrennt (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                          
926                                     NaN   
927                                     NaN   
928                                     NaN   
929                                     NaN   
930                                     NaN   
931                                     NaN   
932                                     NaN   
933                           Protokolliert   
934                                     NaN   
935                                     NaN   

     Host verbunden (LGR S/N: 20009596) Angehalten (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                                                     
926                                 NaN                            NaN   
927                                 NaN                            NaN   
928                                 NaN                            NaN   
929                                 NaN                            NaN   
930                                 NaN                            NaN   
931                                 NaN                            NaN   
932                                 NaN                            NaN   
933                                 NaN                            NaN   
934                       Protokolliert                            NaN   
935                                 NaN                  Protokolliert   

     Dateiende (LGR S/N: 20009596)  
Anz.                                
926                            NaN  
927                            NaN  
928                            NaN  
929                            NaN  
930                            NaN  
931                            NaN  
932                            NaN  
933                            NaN  
934                            NaN  
935                  Protokolliert
```

And this is how I want it to be (I left the index how it was to make it more visible):

```
              Datum Zeit   Zeitzone  \
Anz.                                  
926  2019-09-17 09:00:00  GMT+02:00   
927  2019-09-17 10:00:00  GMT+02:00   
928  2019-09-17 11:00:00  GMT+02:00   
929  2019-09-17 12:00:00  GMT+02:00   
930  2019-09-17 13:00:00  GMT+02:00   
931  2019-09-17 13:10:32  GMT+02:00   
935  2019-09-17 13:11:53  GMT+02:00   

      Temp., °C (LGR S/N: 20009596, SEN S/N: 20009596, LBL: 1m)  \
Anz.                                                              
926                                              12.401           
927                                              13.942           
928                                              15.760           
929                                              15.569           
930                                              15.187           
931                                                 NaN           
935                                                 NaN           

      Event, units (LGR S/N: 20009596, SEN S/N: 20009596, LBL: 0,2 mm Niederschlag)  \
Anz.                                                                                  
926                                                 NaN                               
927                                                 NaN                               
928                                                 NaN                               
929                                                 NaN                               
930                                                 NaN                               
931                                               163.0                               
935                                               163.0                               

     Notiz Koppler verbunden (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                               
926                                          NaN   
927                                          NaN   
928                                          NaN   
929                                          NaN   
930                                          NaN   
931                                          NaN   
935                                          NaN   

     Koppler abgetrennt (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                          
926                                     NaN   
927                                     NaN   
928                                     NaN   
929                                     NaN   
930                                     NaN   
931                                     NaN   
935                                     NaN   

     Host verbunden (LGR S/N: 20009596) Angehalten (LGR S/N: 20009596)  \
Anz.                                                                     
926                                 NaN                            NaN   
927                                 NaN                            NaN   
928                                 NaN                            NaN   
929                                 NaN                            NaN   
930                                 NaN                            NaN   
931                                 NaN                            NaN   
935                                 NaN                  Protokolliert   

     Dateiende (LGR S/N: 20009596)  
Anz.                                
926                            NaN  
927                            NaN  
928                            NaN  
929                            NaN  
930                            NaN  
931                            NaN  
935                  Protokolliert
```

Comment: Please always include an example DataFrame, and an example of the desired result in your questions.  You should be able to select the columns with df.iloc[:, [0,1]]

Comment: @B.Bogart I included the dataframes. I know how to select the columns with iloc, I just don't know how to delete the rows based only on these columns. Please read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting the rows that you do not want, try keeping those that you want:

```
df[df.iloc[:,[2,3]].notnull().all(axis=1)]
```

But what is wrong with getting the column names by index?

```
df.dropna(subset=df.columns[[2,3]])
```

Comment: I tried both codes but the result is a blank dataframe (only header)

Comment: I modified the second proposal and it worked:
`df.dropna(subset=df.columns[[2,3]], how='all')`